# Closure of an Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. The $cl(G)$ (i.e. the [closure](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/glossary.htm) of $G$) is the graph obtained by adding edges between non-adjacent vertices whose degree sum is at least $n$, until this can no longer be done.
[image]

> $\textbf{Question:}$ I have $\textbf{two}$ separate graphs above (i.e. one on the left and one on the right). What is the closure of both of these graphs looking at them again separately? I am having a hard time understanding this definition and a description of where the edges would go would be very helpful between vertices.

Comment: Is the closure of a graph saying that we add edges between every vertex so they touch? I am not concerned about using this definition in particular, just a definition that someone knows works for undirected graphs. I think for the graph on the left to add the following edges: $\lbrace v_1, v_2\rbrace$, $\lbrace v_1, v_4\rbrace$ just so all the vertices have endpoints between them, but I am not sure.

Comment: I get the impression that this definition is intended for simple graphs. because loops and multiple edges complicate the degree. That said, the definition should extend to non-simple graphs.

Comment: I got that impression as a possibility too. The reason I want this definition is to look at Ore's Theorem which does use simple graphs which makes sense as to what you are saying as the definition might only apply to simple graphs. It might be more generalizable too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first graph, no more edges can be added, because the pairs $(v_1,v_2)$ and $(v_1,v_4)$ have degree sum $3$, and every other pair is already adjacent. So this graph is its own closure.

For the second graph, we can add edges $v_1v_3$ and $v_2v_4$ immediately, since for both pairs the degree sum is $4$. Now the degree sum of $v_1,v_4$ is $5$, so we can add this edge too (note that we could not add this edge initially). There are no more non-adjacent pairs, so we've reached the closure.

The point of this definition is that a *simple* graph is Hamiltonian if and only if its closure is Hamiltonian - this is the [Bondy-Chvátal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem) theorem.

Comment: Is the closure in this sense always unique for an arbitrary graph?

Comment: @Michael Yes, because degrees never go down in this process. Construct a closure by adding edges in some order. By induction on $r$, the $r$th edge you added (say it is $uv$) must eventually be added in any construction of the closure - once all the previous $r-1$ edges have been added we must have $d(u)+d(v)\geq n$.

Answer (score 2):

If I don't misunderstand the definition, the following graphs must be the closure of your graphs:

[image]

The first graph stays as it was because $d(v_1)+d(v_2) = 3 < 4$ and $d(v_1) + d(v_4) = 3 < 4$ and rest of the vertex pairs are already adjacent.

In the second graph, my answer stays the same but with a little difference: Order of adding edges matters here because if we try to add $e_7$ first, then since $d(v_1) + d(v_4) = 3 < 4$, we can't do that. Therefore, we first add $e_5$ and $e_6$, then $e_7$ to get the graph above. After adding these three edges, since each vertex becomes adjacent to other vertices, we can no longer add an edge.

Comment: I think that the definition means the degree before adding the new edges, not after. Hence, the graph on the left should already be closed.

Comment: But definition says *at least* so I think we can still add an edge unless we have all the vertices adjacent. But according to your understanding, my calculation on degree sums may change.

Comment: I really like the picture :)

Comment: I found [an example](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mrm/Teaching/DiscreteMaths/LectureNotes/HamiltonBondyAndChvatal.pdf) from some lecture notes on the front page of google, and if you look at figure 12.1 on page 4, it only adds an edge between the vertices which already have degree sum at least $n$. At the last stage, for example, vertices $3$ and $7$ have degrees $4$ and $1$ respectively, and adding an edge between them would make their degree sum $7$, but that edge is never added.

Comment: How do you justify adding _either_ of the red edges to the left? No matter which one you start with, the sum of the degrees of $v_1$ and $v_4$ (or $v_1$ and $v_2$) is only $3$, which is **not** $\ge n$, because $n=4$.

Comment: I just saw your comments and the example that OP gave. Sorry for misunderstanding the definition from the start, I will edit my answer right now.