# Is there any operation involved related to closure of a graph? What is the motivation behind defining closure of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Do we always use the word **closure** under some *operation*? Usually, I have used the word closure as the set we get after adding element in a set to make that set self content under some operation. For example, closure of $\{1,2,3\}$ under *addition* is $\mathbb{N}$. Here we are saying closure *under addition*.

In graph theory, I am not getting if there any operation involved while defining closure of a graph. Is there any operation involved while we are defining closure of a graph ? I want to know the motivation of defining **closure** of a graph in the way it is [defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896482/closure-of-an-undirected-graph).

Comment: "Closure" is a word that has many different meanings, sometimes different from the one you mention.