# Prove this $2$-connected graph has a hamilton cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I meet with this problem in my homework. It asks me to use a special trick to prove **theorem 1** in the following  essay.

[New sufficient condition for cycles in graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895684900546)

The trick is : **A simple undirected graph G is Hamiltonian if and only if its closure c(G) is Hamiltonian.**

The definition of the closure of graphs can be seen here:[Definition of the closure of undirected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896482/closure-of-an-undirected-graph)

I would appreciate if anyone could help

Comment: What have you tried? Have you ever used this trick (also known as the Bondy–Chvátal theorem) before?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I just found the condition in the theorem 1 of the essay hard to be related to the Bondy–Chvátal theorem. I have used this trick in proving some other trivial theorems like "If the degree sum of every two nonadjacent vertexes is at least |V(G)| ,then G is Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1 in the paper you're citing says

> Let $G$ be a $2$-connected graph on $n\ge 3$ vertices. If, for every two distinct vertices $u,v$ of $G$, $$d(u,v) = 2 \implies \max \{\deg(u), \deg(v)\} \ge \frac n2$$ then $G$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

I have rephrased slightly to make the order of quantifiers more clear.

---

To get you started: let $A$ be the set of vertices of $G$ with degree at least $\frac n2$, and let $B$ be the set of all other vertices. Then:

- Each component of the induced graph $G[B]$ is a clique. (Why?)
- Each vertex of $A$ has edges to at most one of these clique components. (Why?)

In the closure of $G$, all edges between vertices in $A$ are added. To find a Hamiltonian cycle in the closure of $G$, proceed as follows:

1. Find vertex-disjoint paths with endpoints in $A$ that cover all of $B$.
2. Join them together using edges in $A$.

Conclude that $G$ also has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: I think the edges connecting A and the component of B should have no common endpoint, without which a construction seems unlikely.  Could you please give any hint to prove the preceding idea or show it's unnecessary? Sorry I have struggle with it for hours..

Comment: The key is that if a vertex $a \in A$ has edges to $b_1, b_2 \in B$, then there must be an edge $b_1b_2$ (or else $d(b_1, b_2) = 2$ is a contradiction), so $b_1$ and $b_2$ are in the same component.

Comment: Sorry I did not express my claim correctly. I just wanted to prove there always exist two disjoint edges between every component of B and A. But I have eventually figured it out through the 2-connectedness. The construction turns natural by means of this property.