# Closure of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I read the following post:

[Closure of an Undirected Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896482/closure-of-an-undirected-graph)

There, the interesting notion of closure of an undirected graph is given. However, the definition is a bit ambiguous. Is the closure of a simple undirected graph a (simple undirected) graph or a multigraph? Well, my question is: are there some good references (books) where I can find such a notion written in a precise formal way? Moreover, can you provide me some basic examples of closure, for instance for complete graphs, complete bipartite graphs, trees, $P_n$, $C_n$ and wheels? Are there other examples in literature?

Comment: http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/math443f12/notes2.pdf

Comment: I know that the closure of a graph is hamiltonian if and only if the graph is hamiltonian. However, the document you sent me does not interest me. I want basic examples, properties and so on. What is a $(p,q)$-graph? I need something specific on the topic: closure of a graph. Is there any good reference (possibly book)?